# In nativescript for IOS can I change the webview browser client

Tags: nativescript-angular

I am using **Nativescript 5** and **Angulat 4**, and I want to change the **Webview** browser client, I want to **load with chrome**.

Is it posible?

And, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO**. A [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) is a view that displays interactive web content, such as for an in-app browser. They do not use any browser, they use [webkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit).

Comment: Because I modify a litle bit the WebView to Android I think it also could works on iOS, thanks.